# Disable a button for 30 seconds

Tags: javascript, html, class

I have a button (where I can't change any of the HMTL) that clicks to save an answer to a question.

I want to disable this button for 30 seconds so that they cannot answer the question unless 30 seconds has passed. I don't know much javascript but I was told this can be used to do this.

Here is the html code that I cant change in any way:

```
<input type="submit" class="btnLarge" value="Submit" name="submit">
```

I thought maybe I can use the getElementByClassName but I'm not sure how that will be called. Can anyone help?

Comment: Thanks everyone. I used one that seems to be deleted now but it worked:

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" >
  window.onload = function()
          {
             var btn = document.getElementsByName('submit')[0];
             btn.disabled  = true;

             setTimeout(function(){btn.disabled  = false;}, 30000);
          };
</script>

Answer (score 4):

Starts with your button *disabled*, Notice added *disabled* attribute

***HTML***

```
<input type="submit" class="btnLarge" value="Submit" name="submit" disabled>
```

***JavaScript***

**If you can't change HTML**

```
 document.getElementsByName("submit")[0].disabled = true;
```

*To enable after 30 seconds*

Here use [**setTimeout**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout), to enable it after 30 seconds. In the anonymus function of setTimeout.

To identify element you can use [**document.getElementsByName**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName), it returns a list of elements with a given name in the (X)HTML document. Thus to access first element `[0]` is used

Modify the [DOM property](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-DOM-Level-2-HTML-20030109/html.html#ID-50886781) is also called disabled and is a boolean that takes true or false.

```
setTimeout(function(){  
    var element = document.getElementsByName("submit")[0] ;
    element.disabled = false;
}, 30000);
```

Complete Code

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementsByName("submit")[0].disabled = true;
    setTimeout(function(){  
        var element = document.getElementsByName("submit")[0] ;
        element.disabled = false;
    }, 30000);
}
```

Comment: OP says s/he can't change the HTML.

Comment: Can't change the html in any way. I can't add to it either. I got one of the answers to work but unfortunately I think they deleted their answer.

Comment: @user3270936, I have provided both options, didn't you noticed that

Comment: couldn't you just refresh the page and the timeout would go away?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        setTimeout (function(){
        document.getElementById('submitButton').disabled = null;
        },30000);

        var countdownNum = 30;
        incTimer();

        function incTimer(){
        setTimeout (function(){
            if(countdownNum != 0){
            countdownNum--;
            document.getElementById('timeLeft').innerHTML = 'Time left: ' + countdownNum + ' seconds';
            incTimer();
            } else {
            document.getElementById('timeLeft').innerHTML = 'Ready!';
            }
        },1000);
        }
    </script>

 <form>
        <input type="submit" disabled="disabled" id="submitButton" />
        <p id="timeLeft">Time Left: 30 seconds</p>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
var element = document.getElementById('submitBtn');
element.disabled = true;
setTimeout(function(){
    element.disabled = false;
}, 30000);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this
in javasript

```
var i=0;
document.getElementsByName('submit')[0].setAttribute("disabled","disabled");
    window.onload = function() {
        window.setTimeout(setdis, 30000);
    }
    function setdis() {
        if(i==0)
        {
           document.getElementsByName('submit')[0].disabled = false;
           i++;
        }
    }
```

good luck

Comment: OP says s/he can't change the HTML.

Comment: it's use `document.getElementsByName`

Answer (score 0):

I would create a re-usable function that takes the specified amount of time and the className as inputs.

```
function disableElementForSpecifiedTime(className, disabledTime_milliseconds)
{
    var element = document.getElementsByClassName(className)[0];
    element.disabled = true;

    setTimeout(function(){  
        element.disabled = false;
    }, disabledTime_milliseconds);
}
```

Call it like this

```
disableElementForSpecifiedTime("btnLarge", 3000)
```

In the name of usability I would recommend highlighting the button when it's enabled, perhaps by making it bigger for a moment, using a jquery animation.

Answer (score 0):

Add the attributes `disabled` and `id="submit-form"` to your button.

```js
window.setTimeout(setEnabled, 30000);

function setEnabled() {
  var submitButton = document.getElementById('submit-form');
  if (submitButton) {
    submitButton.disabled = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" class="btnLarge" value="Submit" name="submit" id="submit-form" disabled>
```

Answer (score -1):

As you can't change the html, you can use javascript functions. Give an id to your button.
Make it disabled on page load.

```
<input type="submit" class="btnLarge" value="Submit" name="submit" disabled="disabled" id="saveAns">
```

Then you can use a timer function to enable it after 30 seconds

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function() { setTimeout(function()
{
    document.getElementById('saveAns').disabled = false;},30000);
}
```